# Graphing in Netlogo

Tags: graph, netlogo, graphing

I need help with my code, I am making a graph where I am diving the population by ticks, which represents time.  When ever I graph it it keeps showing the wrong numbers on the graph.  If my population is 1000 and its on the second tick, it should be 500, but on the graph it shows 500 on the first tick.  [This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRo0i.png)

```
globals [

]
to setup  ;; resets everything to appropriate initial values
clear-all

reset-ticks
end
to go
tick
update-and-plot
end


to update-and-plot  ;; updates values for plot
update-and-plot-m/n

end

to update-and-plot-m/n
set-current-plot "Population"

plot (  NUm /  ticks ) 
end
```

Comment: @Charles - you should do your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted

Answer (score 1):

The `tick` command is also what updates the plots, so your plot is not being updated until the beginning of the next tick. Try putting `tick` at the end of the `go` procedure, where it normally goes. (You may then need to check for `ticks = 0` in your plotting procedure since ticks starts at zero.)

Comment: Or put your plotting code in the plot itself. If you do it that way, as recommended in the NetLogo User Manual and demonstrated in any model in the NetLogo's Models Library that has a plot, the plot will update itself at `reset-ticks` and `tick` time. You don't need to use `set-current-plot`, or any other plotting code at all, in the Code tab.